# XMLHttpRequest cannot load google form

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xmlhttprequest, google-forms

I am having the following form on my page:

```
    <iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" onload=
"if(submitted) {window.location='thank-you.html';}" style=
"display:none;"></iframe>

<div class="form-wrap" id="newsletter">
    <form action=
    "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ckysxoBGBaN_sKGFVda2D0cxR0muzhm6LeUb3PDfId0/formResponse"
    class="newsletter-form" id="newsletter-form" method="post" name=
    "newsletter-form" onsubmit="submitted=true;" target="hidden_iframe">
        <input class="ss-q-short" dir="auto" id="entry_1476137342" name=
        "entry.1476137342" required="" title="Must be a valid email address"
        type="email" value=""> <input name="draftResponse" type="hidden" value=
        "[,,&quot;1794978808793485775&quot;]"> <input name="pageHistory" type=
        "hidden" value="0"> <input name="fbzx" type="hidden" value=
        "1794978808793485775"> <input id="ss-submit" name="submit" type=
        "submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see this form is basically a google form, which, when submitted should redirect to a `thank-you.html` page. Basically this definitely should work, however I am getting in the chrome console:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ckysxoBGBaN_sKGFVda2D0cxR0muzhm6LeUb3PDfId0/formResponse. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Any recommendations why?

I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: @Quentin thx for your suggestion! Can you please explain, why you redirected me? I don`t understand...

Comment: You got an error message telling you (if you did any research into it) that you are violating the same origin policy, therefore your question is asking how to work around the same origin policy.

Comment: @Quentin ok have it, I am not allowed in google forms to change theur `<form>` id!